# Adobe Premiere Hide Clip Keyframes or remove the Adjustment line?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe

How can you remove this particular line here? Apperantly when you right click on a clip you can see clip keyframes and select something like time rewrapping, however you can not unselect it, but apperantly you can hide it, I just don't know how.

Does anybody know or is this normal and default not sure.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/jIZZoVS.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the timeline there is a wrench icon and here it shows the option to hide the video keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, click the icon indicated by the arrow in the following image and select “Hide Keyframes” form the menu that pops up.

The icon is under the camera icon on your timeline.

Comment: Where? Do you have an image please? You got that from here? https://www.pointsinfocus.com/learning/quickref/ I don't see that icon at all.